# How to show a label after same second in a VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering how to do that in VB.NET. Imagine we have a form that has 4 labels that are hidden. What I want to do is to show them one after each other with delay. For example, when I run my app first show the first label after 5 second show the second one and after another 5 second show other one and so on. I know I should use timer and write my code in tick but I don't know how. Just tell me the timer code. I can do the rest of that.

Comment: Just tell me your effort.

Comment: Google can give you plenty of examples.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Comment: The code is `l(n).Show()`. Got it?

Comment: label1.show()    it just shows the label. but I want to show it after 5 second and another label after 5 second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming WinForms?  One way it could be done...

```
Public Class Form1

    Private LabelsEnumerator As IEnumerator

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Labels() As Label = {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4}
        For Each lbl As Label In Labels
            lbl.Hide()
        Next
        LabelsEnumerator = Labels.GetEnumerator
        Timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5).TotalMilliseconds
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If Not IsNothing(LabelsEnumerator) Then
            If LabelsEnumerator.MoveNext Then
                LabelsEnumerator.Current.Show()
            Else
                Timer1.Stop()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a stopwatch?

Create a Timer1 and set to say 100ms tick. Then declare the following

```
Private stopwatch As New Stopwatch
```

Then on form load have:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
    Me.stopwatch.Start()
End Sub
```

Then for Timer1 tick event:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If (Me.stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds >= 5) AndAlso (Me.stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds <= 6) Then
            If Label1.Visible = False Then
                Label1.Visible = True
            End If
        End If

        If (Me.stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds >= 10) AndAlso (Me.stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds <= 11) Then
            If Label2.Visible = False Then
                Label2.Visible = True
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

An easy option if you have a limited number of labels to show and you don't always want the time between each show to be the same interval.